# Custom Read More text

Tags: joomla-3.x, com-content, readmore

Is it possible to set a custom **Read more** text for each article in Joomla? I would like to be able to somehow set a unique text for some of the readmore links (added using `<hr id="system-readmore" />` in my articles.

Example: <kbd>Read more...</kbd>, <kbd>Keep reading...</kbd> or <kbd>Explore...</kbd>

Language overrides won't work, because that would change all the links. I know I could create a button and link it to another article, but that's not an ideal solution either.

In WordPress you can use `<!--more Keep reading-->` to set a custom text for a particular button, does Joomla have a similar option (or another way of solving this)?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

Yes is posible, go to each article, from here you can see a Tab called **Options**
at the bottom you can see the field **Read More Text**, see the screenshot.

[image]

Regards.